# Excel CustomUI Button Links

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, ribbonx

Ok, I know this is an ongoing problem, and I have searched seemingly everywhere for an answer. I apologize if I somehow missed an answer on here, so if you know of one, please advise!

I created a Custom Ribbon in Excel using the 'CustomUI Editor". My macros currently only run from buttons directly on the sheet, not on the UI. I read that it is because of the links to the original file. So I created a fresh new workbook, created new macros (not imported), created custom UI buttons, and linked the macros to the new buttons. The buttons still give me the error that the macro cannot be run and may not be available. What could I be missing here? I have also read that its possible to create a macro to update the links when the workbook is opened. Has anyone had success with this? I would love to have buttons on the ribbon and remove them from my sheet! Thanks for any help that you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sub to add custom menu items. Just replace the .OnAction value with the names of the macros you'd like the control to run.

```
Sub AddCustomMenu()
    Dim cbMainMenuBar As CommandBar
    Dim iHelpMenu As Integer
    Dim cbcCutomMenu As CommandBarControl

    'Delete the menu item if it already exists. Use On Error Resume Next in case it doesn't exist.
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("&My Tools").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set cbMainMenuBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")   'Set a CommandBar variable to Worksheet menu bar

    iHelpMenu = cbMainMenuBar.Controls("Help").Index    'Return the Index number of the Help menu. We can then use this to place a custom menu before.
    Set cbcCutomMenu = cbMainMenuBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=iHelpMenu) 'Add a Control to the "Worksheet Menu Bar" before Help.
    cbcCutomMenu.Caption = "&My Tools"  'Give the control a caption

    'Working with our new Control, add a sub control and give it a Caption and tell it which macro to run (OnAction).
    With cbcCutomMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        .Caption = "Run Macro 1"
        .OnAction = "Macro1"
    End With

    With cbcCutomMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        .Caption = "Run Macro 2"
        .OnAction = "Macro2"
    End With
End Sub
```

If you'd like it to add your custom menu whenever you open the workbook, go to the ThisWorkbook module and add the following sub:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    AddCustomMenu
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Is there a way to remove it when the workbook closes?